# How to animate arrayed objects individually

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, objects, animation-nodes

I'm trying to achieve this "growing" city effect using array modifiers to create a grid and then animating the grid so the objects move up from the floor into place. I managed to achieve this effect in C4D (as pictured below), but can't seem to achieve it in Blender.

I'm guessing the solution is pretty simple. Anything related with animating the Y position with some sort of delay. I just can't figure out how. Any ideas?

[image: I managed to achieve the effect in c4D]

Comment: tbh honest i have no idea how the animation should look like. Can u pls add a link to an animation how it should look like? thx

Comment: "Arrayed Objects" aren't really individual objects, just one large mesh, so can't be easily animated independently. Either use individual objects or look into Geometry Nodes

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think array modifiers can do this for you, but geometry nodes with a point distribute on a grid mesh primitive can. I would base the effect on distance from a starting point, probably an empty. To get the effect, have math nodes set up to get a point’s distance from the empty, subtracts an animated value from it that starts at zero and gets larger, subtract the result from 1, clip that to a 0-1 range, and use that to drive the extrusion / Z transformation of each individual building instance. What you get is a gradient ring from zero to one that expands outward from the empty and leaves a solid 1 circle inside it. The gradient will only be 1 m long, so you may want to make the animated value subtract from a value other than 1 and then divide it by that same value, to make the gradient that value long.

I hope I did this right in my head, I haven’t tested it, as Blender isn’t installed on my machine at the moment.